# Add months to variable date in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm looking to calculate 6 months from a variable date. I have list of names and the date they last logged in. In groovy, how do I add 6 months to any given date?

the variable containing dates is lastloggedin. It is of date type and in format yyyy-MM-dd

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

use (TimeCategory) {
    sixmonthsfromnow = lastloggedin + 6.month
}
```

Example result:

if lastloggedin = 2021-01-02, the result = "2021-01-026month"

Comment: can you show the code with your effort ? and some expected output ?

Comment: @Deadpool apologies I'm brand new to stackoverflow. Updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the string into [LocalDate](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/time/LocalDate.html)

```
def someDate = LocalDate.parse('2021-01-02', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Or if you have the [Date](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html) type, you can convert it into `LocalDate` and then add months

```
date.toLocalDate() + 6.month
```

And then add months to it

```
someDate + 6.month
```

Or by using [TimeCategory](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html)

```
def format = "yyyy-MM-dd"
def date = new Date()
def formattedDate = today.format(format)

use(TimeCategory) {
    def oneYear = today + 6.month
}
```